# Why Ubuntu sets system's hostname for my public IP?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, connection, hostname

In various network utilities, Ubuntu 18.04 displays my public IP address with the system hostname. Let's imagine that 12.34.56.78 is my public IP and 9.8.7.6 is some client's IP. For example, if I look at the list of connected ssh-clients, I see the following:

Variant 1:

```bash
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~# lsof -i :22
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    19486 root    3u  IPv4 5115409      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    19486 root    4u  IPv6 5115411      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    19840 root    3u  IPv4 5116401      0t0  TCP ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:ssh->here.is.client.hostname.com:36662 (ESTABLISHED)
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~#
```

Variant 2:

```bash
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~# lsof -n -i :22
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    19486 root    3u  IPv4 5115409      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    19486 root    4u  IPv6 5115411      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    19840 root    3u  IPv4 5116401      0t0  TCP 12.34.56.78:ssh->9.8.7.6:36662 (ESTABLISHED)
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~#
```

Or traceroute:

```bash
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~# traceroute 12.34.56.78
traceroute to 12.34.56.78 (12.34.56.78), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel (12.34.56.78)  0.057 ms  0.032 ms  0.017 ms
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~#
```

I noticed on another machine with the same version of the Ubuntu there is no such thing. How to stop Ubuntu setting default hostname for public IP?

P.S.
If I have more than one public IP on machine and if IP address doesn't have reverse DNS, Ubuntu sets default hostname for all of them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just realized that Ubuntu was using local DNS-server, which was adding hostname to server's IP addresses. I should have changed DNS-server in `/etc/resolv.conf`